# Подскажите как обратиться к кнопке созданной в js

Tags: javascript, button, click

1. Создаю див с разметкой answDiv
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Очищаю существующий див и добавляю туда answDiv
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   получается что в новой разметке я создал кнопки с id "AnswerOne" "AnswerTwo" подскажите пожалуйста, как мне и когда нужно обратиться чтобы я смог повесить действие на клик по ним, сейчас консоль даже при console.log выдает вместо кнопки null [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К самим кнопкам сейчас я обращаюсь после этой функции, но уже пробовал по разному
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://github.com/ScherbakovM/quiz.git

Comment: Михаил, под вопросом есть кнопочка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1463368/edit) добавьте пожалуйста Ваш код в вопрос, там есть спец кнопка `{}` для вставки кода

Comment: @DaniilLoban, воспроизводимый пример лучше создавать с помощью кнопки `<>`